# R: compare words histogram by document

Tags: r, text, text-mining, corpus

I am looking for a method to compare word histograms by documents belong to a folder corpus with several documnets. I did try to made:

```
freq <- sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm), group=Docs), decreasing=TRUE)
```

Also and did try in ggplot option:

```
p <- p + geom_bar(stat="identity") +   facet_wrap(~ Docs)
```

but lamentably I got error.

An modified example of my code is below, but lamentably my 3 documents are plot like one and nor segmented by Docs:

```
c= c("hola como  hola como  hola como", "hola me fui hola me fui hola me fui hola me fui", "hola como estas hola como estas hola como estas" )
corpus= VCorpus(VectorSource(c))

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)

m <- as.matrix(dtm)   
m 
freq <- sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm)), decreasing=TRUE)  
wf <- data.frame(word=names(freq), freq=freq)   

p <- ggplot(subset(wf, freq>1), aes(word, freq))    
p <- p + geom_bar(stat="identity") 
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) 
p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you create wf means you are losing your docs and they are not available for ggplot2. I create wf as a combination of the document names and the dtm. (Be careful here if you have a big corpus.) Then I turn wf in a long format so ggplot is very nice format for ggplot2. Then just docs in whatever way you need when you create your plots. In the example below I split the graphs between the docs.

```
library(tm)

c= c("hola como  hola como  hola como", "hola me fui hola me fui hola me fui hola me fui", "hola como estas hola como estas hola como estas" )
corpus= VCorpus(VectorSource(c))

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)

wf <- data.frame(docs=Docs(dtm), as.matrix(dtm)) 

library(tidyr)
wf <- wf %>% gather(key = "terms", value = "freq", -docs)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(wf, aes(terms, freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ docs) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
```

[image]